# Replacing locknut and washer on threaded headset with threadlocker on threaded race

Tags: headset

Would that work? It seems like there's not much to prevent the locknut from coming loose anyways, thus making threadlocker necessary. Then, why not put it on the threaded race directly?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand how counter-rotated nuts work to reduce the potential for unwanted unwinding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I haven't done it, I think yes it could work in theory, but the challenge would be doing it in a way that was resistant enough to movement while also not being overly stuck when you need to adjust it. It also wouldn't be practical.

The kinds of threadlockers or retaining compounds that reliably immobilize threads with no preload or other mechanical locking are very high-strength and on the more permanent end of the spectrum. Typically they need heat to loosen. They also need their prep instructions followed exactly, typically involving a fully degreased surface and sufficient cure time and sometimes also a two-stage application. You need very high certainty it's not going to go anywhere, because it will be one non-preloaded nut that's holding your fork on. You'll also need to go through it all over again whenever the headset needs adjusting, and at that point it's pretty clearly not worth it.

The adjustable race does get some twisting force on it while riding, enough that somewhat undertightened-but-not-loose locknuts can eventually allow movement. I think you would need quite a bit of holding power out of the threadlocker.

Properly torqued headset locknuts are very resistant to coming loose. Threadlocker is not necessary. It's true that pre-applied factory threadlocker can be found on some headsets and forks today, but as with many cases of factory threadlocker on bike parts it more comes from a mindset of assembly convenience or a "something is better than nothing, and if we don't pre-apply it people will assemble it dry" mentality. Good threaded headsets have no issue staying in place with just grease on the threads.

Comment: Perhaps threadlockers weren't such a thing back in the late 19th century when the safety bike was first built?   Whereas locknuts were a common engineering method.